# SharePoint - How to search for a PDF based on it's meta data?

Tags: managed-metadata, metadata

Within SharePoint 2010, or 2013, it is possible for SharePoint to bring up PDF search results based on PDF document meta data?

If I create the PDF document in Photoshop, and add Meta Data to this document, and then try to search for this document in SharePoint based on some word I wrote for it's meta data, will the search results page display that document?

Is there a setting to make this happen, or is this an automatic feature of SharePoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make SharePoint Enterprise 2010 search PDF file, you should follow some necessary steps and download the PDF ifilter as explained here:
http://www.foxitsoftware.com/german/products/ifilter/installation.php

Foxit PDF iFilter is a paid one but the performance is better than other iFilters.

As already explained by Waqas, SharePoint 2013 now supports PDF iFilter natively.
PDF icon is natively supported in SharePoint 2013 results and document libraries without any additional configuration or installation of software in SharePoint 2013 farm. There is no need to install Adobe’s free PDF ifilter or Foxit PDF iFilter like SharePoint 2010 or MOSS 2007. This is simply available in out of the box configuration.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2013 Search now supports PDF iFilter natively. This means that you get out of the box functionality, without need to go online and configure your Farm with iFilters. It also read embedded metadata, such as Author

http://sharepointthing.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/sharepoint-2013-search-natively-supports-pdf-ifilter/